# How to wait for a method to finish on another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to multi-thread programming in C#. My problem is that I don't know how to wait for a method that is being run on another thread to finish, before it can continue to the next line. For example, something like this

```
public class A
{    
    int i;

    public A()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    protected void RunLoop()
    {
        while(i < 100)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        TimerResolution.TimeBeginPeriod(1);
        runThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunLoop));
        running = true;
        runThread.Start();
    }
}

public class B
{
    A classAInstance = new A();
    A.Start();
    Console.Writeline(i);
}
```

Right now, it prints 0 on the console, which is not what I want (i.e. i = 100).
What is the best way to do this? BTW, I don't have access to the *`runThread`* that is created in *`class A`*

Thanks.

EDIT:

It was a bit difficult to solve this problem without modifying a lot codes. Therefore, we ended up with adding a condition in the `public void Start()` with which it can decide whether to run the `RunLoop` in a separate thread or not. The condition was defined using an `Enum` field.

```
public void Start()
{
    TimerResolution.TimeBeginPeriod(1);
    running = true;
    if (runningMode == RunningMode.Asynchronous)
    {
        runThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunLoop));
        runThread.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        RunLoop();
    }
}
```

And

```
public enum RunningMode { Asynchronous, Synchronous };
```

Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: If you have no access to the other code, you can't possibly detect what's happening on the other thread. If you have access to the thread instance, you can wait for it to finish using `Thread.Join`, but if you don't even have that, the problem is unsolvable. Synchronization requires cooperation.

Comment: Incidentally, your code can't compile since we have no access to `A.i` either (and if we did, it wouldn't be thread-safe). So, do your threads share state or don't they? What's your *actual* problem, and why do you think it requires explicit threading?

Comment: *Instead* of using threads, use Tasks and `await`, `ContinueWith`, `Wait()` etc to take some action when the task finishes. They were created to simplify the scenario you describe (at a minimum)

Comment: The point of using threads is to allow something to process and **not wait** for it. Your example code is exactly where you wouldn't use threads. Would it be worth trying to come up with an example that better suits what you're really trying to do?

Comment: It would be super awesome if your code compiled - we need a [mcve] to really help.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks for your comment. The reason we are using thread is that we are writing a windows form application in which we run a bunch of codes. That's the reason for using threads.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks. I will try it and see how it works.

Comment: @Enigmativity, that's true. But, since I am not responsible for that part of the code, I can't change it.

Comment: @SinaTorabi - Can you post the real code then?

Comment: @Enigmativity, unfortunately not. But I am trying to find a better way to explain it. And, also, I'm going to talk to the person who is working with that part, to see if we can come up with a solution. I will post it here when it is solved.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred method is to use the [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (TPL) and use `Task` with `await`.

If you must use Threads, then use a [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) or [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx) to signal the end of a method.

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A();
    a.Start();
    a.FinishedEvent.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine(a.Index);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class A
{
    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    int i;

    public EventWaitHandle FinishedEvent
    {
        get { return mre; }
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get { return i; }
    }

    public A()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    protected void RunLoop()
    {
        while (i < 1000)
        {
            i++;
        }
        mre.Set();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var runThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunLoop));
        runThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your life would be so much better with tasks.

Your code could be this simple:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
});

Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
```

Comment: You'd need a `task.Wait()` there, the OP is asking how to wait for the process to finish

Comment: @Jcl, `task.Result` is a blocking call, same as `task.Wait()`

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy ohhh, that's totally right, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

I like use Monitor.Wait() and Monitor.Pulse() in conjunction with "lock" operator. It works, but you must be careful, when you use this technique.
I'm added some changes to your code to demonstrate it. Code below are prints i== 100, as you want.

```
public class A
{
    int i;

    public object SyncObject
    {  get; private set; }

    public A()
    {
        SyncObject = new object();
        i = 0;
    }

    protected void RunLoop()
    {
        while (i < 100)
        {
            i++;
        }

        lock (SyncObject)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(SyncObject);
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var runThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunLoop));
        runThread.Start();
    }

    public void PrintI()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I == " + i);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        A classAInstance = new A();
        lock (classAInstance.SyncObject)
        {
            classAInstance.Start();
            Monitor.Wait(classAInstance.SyncObject);
        }
        classAInstance.PrintI();
    }
}
```